# Check if server is https doesn't work

Tags: php, https

I'm trying to check if a server has `https enabled` but it never goes into the if, but in the else statement.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "yes") {
    echo "HTTPS";
} else {
     echo "HTTP";
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I would echo the server[https] variable. Depending on the server it may be 'on' not 'yes'.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

> 'HTTPS'
>       Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.

But it also adds:

> ```
> Note: Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be off if the request was not made through the HTTPS protocol.
> ```

So, I would use a different logic:

```
<code>
if ( empty( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
    echo 'http:';
}
else if ( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off' ) {
    echo 'http:';
}
else {
    echo 'https:';
}
</code>
```

This way it does not matter if it is "on" or "yes".
However, I do not have an environment to test this for the https case.
http works in my case.